# Smallest Capacitor for Flyback AC/DC Converter

Tags: capacitance, ac-dc

Most of the isolated flyback AC/DC converters I’ve seen place a rather large (>1uF) electrolytic capacitor in parallel with the bridge rectifier that follows the AC voltage source. To provide a specific example, [this](https://www.newark.com/murata-power-solutions/bac1s05sc/power-supply-ac-dc-5v-0-2a/dp/73AH2151?st=Murata%20ac/dc%205V) part from Murata needs a 6.8uF rated at 400V which can make the device rather bulky. If I’m looking to only generate 100mW @5V from a 120VAC supply instead of 1W, can I get away with using a ceramic capacitor with a much lower capacitance value (rated for the same AC voltage)?

[image]

My second question would then be: is there a general formula available I could use to determine what size capacitance I need to provide a certain output DC power? (Like 100nF for 50mW, 200nF for 75mW, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Surely the capacitor is across the DC source after the rectifier? No formula, but you can easily calculate the approximate ripple voltage you'll get at a particular current for any given capacitance. It's up to you to decide if that ripple is acceptable.

Comment: Depending upon which country a device is being used/sold in, there may be legal requirements related to power factor and electro-magnetic interference for a switching power supply. These legal requirements may have some influence upon the range of capacitors that are acceptable.

Comment: *Most of the isolated flyback AC/DC converters I’ve seen place a rather large (>1uF) electrolytic capacitor in parallel with the AC voltage source.* - no they don't.

Comment: @BrianDrummond you are correct I misspoke: capacitor comes after the rectifier. If that capacitor is solely for mitigating ripple, could I make it produce ‘terrible ripple’ and then correct the issue on the secondary side? So add a larger capacitor after the isolation

Comment: @cdubs It's up to you to decide if that ripple is acceptable

Comment: @BrianDrummond ok that’s fair. Could a flyback AC/DC converter still operate in theory with no smoothing capacitor on the high side at all? Or will the PWM generator not function

Comment: At some input voltage, and worst case load, the PWM can't sustain the output.